# Considering $0<s$ for the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{i^s}$, show that $a_{2^{n+1} -1}$ $<\sum_{j=0}^{n}$ $({\frac {1} {2^{s-1}})}^j$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

***Problem:*** Considering $0<s<1$ for the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{i^s}$, I want to show that $a_{2^{n+1} -1}$ $<\sum_{j=0}^{n}$ $({\frac {1} {2^{s-1}})}^j$ where $a_n$ is the partial sums of the aforementioned series..

So for $n=1$ this would yield the inequality:

$\frac {1}{1^s} +\frac {1}{2^s} + \frac {1}{3^s}+ \frac {1}{4^s} < (\frac {1} {2^{s-1}})^{0} + (\frac {1} {2^{s-1}})^{1}=1+\frac {1} {2^{s-1}}$ which would imply that
$\frac {1} {2^{s-1}}  > \frac {1}{2^s} + \frac {1}{3^s} + \frac {1}{4^s} $

which I think I can show since $ \frac {1}{2^s} + \frac {1}{3^s} + \frac {1}{4^s} < \frac {3} {2^{s-1}} < \frac {2} {2^{s-1}}= \frac {1} {2^s} < \frac {1} {2^{s-1}}$.

I just need a way to generalize this notion of grouping the terms in groups of $log_2$ to complete the desired statement. Any hints/help appreciated.

**Edit:** It seems as if I have mis-written the question several times. I will post it from the notes I have and if it is deemed an invalid question, well then I guess we have our answer. We are answering part (b)

Comment: [Cauchy condensation test?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Comment: Sorry about the nitpicking, but this may help in preventing downvotes: the first sum should start at $i=1$.

Comment: @HazemOrabi that is incorrect, you are missing the first term on the left, and the second term on the right

Comment: @HazemOrabi you are right, the question was badly worded, will edit.

Comment: In my opinion, it seems the inequality holds for all $\,s\gt\alpha\ge0\,$, where $\,\alpha\,$ is constant depends on $\,n\,$. Can you double check this assumption?

Comment: @HazemOrabi sorry about the confusion I have posted the exact statement from my notes. It is question (b)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. The problem is still exist even if $\,s\gt1\,$. $$ s=6/5,\,n=1\quad\Rightarrow\quad{\large1}+\frac{1}{{\large2}^{\small6/5}}+\frac{1}{{\large3}^{\small6/5}}+\frac{1}{{\large4}^{\small6/5}}\approx1.89232 \,\color{red}{\large\gt}\, {\large1}+\frac{1}{{\large2}^{\small1/5}}\approx1.87055 $$

Comment: Ok if you post that the question is flawed I will give you the bounty.

Comment: Let us wait and see. I believe something is wrong or missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \begin{align} 
{\large\sum_{\normalsize i=1}^{\normalsize 2^{n+1}}}\frac{1}{i^s} &= \left[\frac{1}{1^s}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+\frac{1}{6^s}+\frac{1}{7^s}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{}{}\cdots\frac{}{}\right]\color{red}{+\frac{1}{\left(2^{n+1}\right)^s}} \\[3mm] 
&\lt \left[\frac{1}{1^s}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{2^s}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{}{}\cdots\frac{}{}\right]\color{red}{+\frac{1}{\left(2^{n+1}\right)^s}} \\[3mm] 
&= \left[\frac{1}{1^s}\right]+\quad\left[\frac{2}{2^s}\right]\quad+\qquad\qquad\left[\frac{4}{4^s}\right]\qquad\qquad+\cdots+\left[\frac{2^n}{\left(2^n\right)^s}\right]\color{red}{+\frac{1}{\left(2^{n+1}\right)^s}} \\[3mm] 
&= \frac{1}{\left(2^0\right)^{s-1}}+\frac{1}{\left(2^1\right)^{s-1}}+\frac{1}{\left(2^2\right)^{s-1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\left(2^n\right)^{s-1}}\color{red}{+\frac{1}{\left(2^{n+1}\right)^s}} \\[3mm] 
&={\large\sum_{\normalsize j=0}^{\normalsize n}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)^j\color{red}{+\frac{1}{\left(2^{n+1}\right)^s}} 
\end{align} $$ 
Hence,
$$ \boxed{ \,\\ \quad {\Huge s_{{\normalsize 2^{n+1}\color{red}{-1}}}}={\large\sum_{\normalsize i=1}^{\normalsize 2^{n+1}\color{red}{-1}}}\frac{1}{i^s} \quad{\Large\lt}\quad {\large\sum_{\normalsize j=0}^{\normalsize n}}\left(\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)^j \qquad\colon\quad s\,\gt\,0 \quad \\\, } $$ 
  
 
NB: Part of this answer is a replication of an existing answer by @B.Mehta with corrections.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: We finally catch it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! will review continually throughout the night.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
a_{2^{n+1}} &= \sum_{i=1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac 1{i^s} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n} \sum_{i=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1} \frac 1{i^s} \\
& \leq \sum_{j=0}^{n} \sum_{i=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1} \frac 1{2^{js}} \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac {2^j}{2^{js}} \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \left(\frac 1{2^{s-1}}\right)^j \\
\end{align}
$$